# Unable to send request over internet in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, restsharp

I constantly get `NameResolutionException` when using `RestSharp` on an Android Emulator in Xamarin.Forms

Below is the code:

```
var restClient = new RestClient("valid server address");

var restRequest = new RestRequest("st/IndexLists", Method.GET)
{
    RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
};

var response = restClient.Execute<object>(restRequest);
```

I'm not able to reach this address from the emulator's browser and also from a device. Other known addresses are reachable.
I'm connected via LAN.

Comment: this is a DNS problem.  You might try using the IP instead, if it's static.

Comment: Thanks. This works. In there any way of resolving the DNS issue?

Comment: Maybe.  You'd need to figure out the underlying issue first.  You may just need to flush the DNS cache on the device.